# Split full address into Street, City, State, Country, Zip

Tags: c#, sql

I know similar questions have been asked, but the situation I'm having now is rather different. I have a collection of addresses which include the following conditions:

1. Some addresses have 5 number zipcode, some of them have 5 number zipcode with 4 extension (Example: 79092 and 93030-7967)
2. Some of the addresses have their organization name appended to the front of the address (I need to remove the organization name) (Example:  Department of Agriculture 1 New Brunswick, New Jersey 08901-8520)
3. Some of them use the short form for the state/country, some of them not (Example: OH and Ohio, USA and United States of America)
4. Foreign addresses from other country where the address pattern is totally different from the US.

Is there any (good) way I can split these addresses into Street, City, State, Country, Zip(where applicable)?

> I am allowed to use SQL SP or C# code

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer because you didn't state how many addresses you have, are they in a database or file? Is each address in a single string? etc.  however, I think you will never get software to do this 100% correct, or even 80%.  your best bet is to get the software to get all the "easy" pattern cases and have some human intervention on the difficult ones.

Comment: If your dataset is large, your time will be better spent buying a third-party package to do this (among other features).  If it's small, I'd just do it "manually" (hand them out) - but note that you'll probably want the package for error checking and correction anyways...

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those problems that comes up all the time - If it is possible in your situation I'd recommend using the Google (or Bing) map APIs to normalize the addresses and then parsing their response.